# Hp Proliant DL360p gen8, Intel 10G ethernet adapter and no access to Inteligent Provisioning

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, intel, provisioning

I have HP Proliant DL360p gen8

and network interfaces:

Intel X520-DA2
Intel I350-T4
and HP 331FLR

There is problem to access Inteligent Provisioning only with Intel X520-DA2 - when this card is enabled, on Inteligent Provisioning we can see white screen with communicates "transfering to 127.0.0.1" and "waiting for 127.0.0.1". This is no matter about network / links connected to this card.

On other cards listed before, Inteligent Prov works fine. So, on enabled Intel X520 something prevent to communicate with localhost / 127.0.0.1.

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please run Intelligent Provisioning with a different network interface.

You can also download the [most recent version](https://buy.hpe.com/us/en/software/server-management-software/server-ilo-management/ilo-management-engine/intelligent-provisioning/p/5219984) of Intelligent Provisioning for your platform to see if it works around this problem.

Comment: With different NICs Inteligent Prov works fine. However, I am configuring this machine to production, and i need this Intel X520-DA2 card. But with this card, this isn't working.

On this link there is Inteligent Prov only to Gen9, Gen10 - I have Gen8 server.

Comment: Your Gen8 server is out of warranty and more than a year beyond the End-of-Service-Life (EOSL) of June 2021.